# Customize interface implementation using WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, code-templates

WebStorm has a handy feature that allows you to quickly implement methods declared by interface. For example:

```js
deserialize: (key: string, value: string) => ISearchFilter;
```

will get auto-implemented to

```js
deserialize(key: string, value: string): ISearchFilter {
    return undefined;
}
```

Is there a way to instruct WebStorm on how the method should be created? In my case, I'd love to see an implemented method throw an error. For example:

```js
deserialize(key: string, value: string): ISearchFilter {
    throw new Error(classname+":deserialize not yet implemented");
    return undefined;
}
```

Is is possible to create such stubs with WebStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the **TypeScript Implemented Method Body** template in **Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates, Code** accordingly